# Mime-type of downloading file

Tags: php, download, mime

i'm trying to create downloadable video-files. In my site there is a list of files.
All videos are in .flv-format (flash). There is exact link to the file for the all videos.
But in all browsers after clicking content is loading to the browser`s window. I needn't in this. As i understand i should create redirect-page wich contains mime-type of the download file. What exactly should i do?
Language: php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a PHP page with the following:

```
<?php

$filepath = "path/to/file.ext";

header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filepath");
header("Content-Type: mime/type");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
// UPDATE: Add the below line to show file size during download.
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));

readfile($filepath);

?>
```

Set `$filepath` to the path of the file to be downloaded, and set `Content-Type` to the mime type of the file being downloaded.

Point the "download" link to this page.

For multiple files of the same type:

```
<?php

$filepath = $_GET['filepath'];

header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filepath");
header("Content-Type: mime/type");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
// UPDATE: Add the below line to show file size during download.
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));

readfile($filepath);

?>
```

Replace the information as specified above, and point the "download" link to this page with a GET parameter named "filepath" containing the file path.

For example, if you name this php file "download.php", point the download link for a file named "movie.mov" (in the same directory as download.php) to "download.php?filepath=movie.mov".

Comment: As i know download.php?filepath=movie.mov isn't good =) Cause everyboady could download any file from server. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Alternatively, you could create one php file for each movie download file.  But that could become tedious.

Comment: Sorry, but your method isn't working =(. After going to the script i got a window from browser to download. It's that what i need, but it downloads file wich is 0 bytes =(

Comment: That's because the file size isn't specified.  You can do this by adding another header:

header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));

Comment: Sorry, it was my problem ;) Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 9):

The recommended MIME type for that is [`application/octet-stream`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-4.5.1):

> The "octet-stream" subtype is used to indicate that a body contains arbitrary binary data. […]
>
> The recommended action for an implementation that receives an "application/octet-stream" entity is to simply offer to put the data in a file, with any Content-Transfer-Encoding undone, or perhaps to use it as input to a user-specified process.