# Changing the mime type of a non-php file?

Tags: php, mime-types

I have a file (*.lwxl)  that I would like for users to download a file, but the mime-type is text/html, and I would like to change it to application. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have access to your Apache configuration *(if you don't want to write a PHP script that will send the headers and the file content)*, maybe the [AddType directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype) can help you :

> The `AddType` directive maps the given
>   filename extensions onto the specified
>   content type. MIME-type is the MIME
>   type to use for filenames containing
>   extension. [...] This directive can be
>   used to add mappings not listed in the
>   MIME types file

The given example looks like this :

```
AddType image/gif .gif
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the appropriate mime type to the `.htaccess` file.

```
AddType application/x-lwxl .lwxl
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set the mime type using a scripting language. Here is how to do it in PHP.

[Mime-type of downloading file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074898/mime-type-of-downloading-file/1074925#1074925)

Comment: this can only work if you are editing the file itself. I'm looking for a way to it externally.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that from PHP - you should do it through your Apache (or IIS or...) config.

For Apache you can edit your `mime.types` file:

```
application/lwxl-type lwxl
```

Comment: Why could you not serve a file from PHP, and set content header?

Comment: Well you could use mod_rewrite to send the request to a PHP file but that seems like a long way around

Answer (score 0):

is that apache?
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html
check AddType Directive