# How to send a file to browser for downloading?

Tags: download, playframework-2.0

When client request for a file, I use this code to send it:

```
public static Result download(String file) {
    File file = getRealFile(file);
    return Ok(file);
}
```

But I found the browser will not download it, but display its content instead. The response header:

```
Content-Type    text/plain
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
```

What's the correct way to send a file?

---

**Update**

Per Razvi's answer, I found an answer seems good for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1074925/342235

But do we really have to set so many headers?

```
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filepath");
header("Content-Type: mime/type");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
// UPDATE: Add the below line to show file size during download.
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the Content-Disposition header. I believe the value of the header should be `attachment`. See [Manipulating the response](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaResponse) doc for this.

For play 2.0 the following works without explicitly setting the header:

`ok(new FileInputStream(file))`

Comment: I thought play2 had some convenient method to do this, unlucky :)

Comment: I found another way to do this, doesn't required explicitly setting the header. :)

Comment: The `renderBinary` one is just for play1 :(

Comment: But you gave me an idea. We can use 'ok(new FileInputStream(file))' in play2, and it works :) Please update your answer, and I will accept it.