# PlayFramework: value as is not a member of Array[Byte]

Tags: scala, playframework

I want to make file download from a database using Play framework. 
But when I use this code I get this message:

> value as is not a member of Array[Byte]

And if I change `Ok(bytOfImage.as("image/jpg"))` to `Ok(bytOfImage)` it works good but I get a file with a name: `secondindex` without `.jpg`

Here's my controller:

```
def secondindex(number: Int) = Action {
    var bytOfImage =  Array[Byte](1)

    val conn = DB.getConnection()
    try {

      val stmt = conn.createStatement
      val rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT image from images where id = " + number)


       while(rs.next()) {
         var blob = rs.getBlob("image")

         bytOfImage = blob.getBytes(1, blob.length().toInt)
         blob.free()
       }

    } finally   {
      conn.close()   }
      Ok(bytOfImage.as("image/jpg"))
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the `as` method on the wrong object. It should look as follows:

```
Ok(bytOfImage).as("image/jpg")
```

Comment: Thank you! It's work! Could you say me please how I can download my image, because now it's showing in browser - but I wanna download.

Comment: You need to set the `Content-Disposition` header to `attachment`. In accordance with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559304/how-to-send-a-file-to-browser-for-downloading answer, you can pass InputStream to the `Ok()` method to set it automatically. Converting your byte array into a stream shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you need download images from browser, you can use method `SimpleResult`
and add in header`"Content-Disposition" -> "attachment"`

For example change row `Ok(bytOfImage.as("image/jpg"))` in you code on

```
val enumImg: Enumerator[Array[Byte]] = { Enumerator(bytOfImage) }
SimpleResult (
 header = ResponseHeader(200, Map("Content-Disposition" -> "attachment")),
 body = enumImg
 )
```