# Chrome starts to display instead of downloading when click a video link

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a simple question and I don't have a clue that how to achieve that.

When I click a video link even I add a `download` attribute, Chrome always show video instead of downloading it.

How can I force it to download video or other file types that display on Chrome by default?

Thanks.

**Update**

In Chrome, you can use `Alt+Click` to force downloading.

But anyway, I need a way that provide simply click to trigger download instead of playing it and if that way work on every browser that will be the best.

Comment: You need to define a different mime-type for that file extension. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074898/mime-type-of-downloading-file) should be helpful

Comment: Do you mean mime-type such as `video/mp4` can't trigger download by default in Chrome?

Comment: Yes, by default Chrome will autoplay the video. You should try with [application/octet-stream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#Important_MIME_types_for_Web_developers)

Comment: I can't change the mime-type, is there any other way?